# is ACL the reason for my buggy module?

Tags: php, magento, module, acl, adminhtml

I've made a custom module that successfully adds a new menu in the admin->configuration section and saves some settings to magento config, and also creates a table at first run/install.  Everything works great locally, but when I move the module to another server I get a 404 error when clicking the link added in the admin area, and nothing seem to work - for maybe a couple of hours.  Eventually it just starts to work.  I've usually just  came back the next day and the 404 is gone and everything works as expected, but if I try to clear all caches, reindex the site, even manually clearing the var folder - nothing will help. It will still give me a 404 error until a couple of hours or a day later.

I don't fully grasp what I should do to avoid the error - but I'm just confused as to how this problem can go away by itself after a while?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the two codebases identical? Does your admin user have a modified role, or does it use the "Administrator" role? And finally, have you tried logging out and logging back in to access your module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common when installing a new extension (that adds Admin pages).  All you need to do is log out, and log back in.